# How to add counter and limit on login attempts per user in Vaadin24 (Java)

Tags: java, security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

We tried adding logic of counter of attempt into beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) method, but it works only before entering username and only on sessions.
The counter code in the beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) method will increment the counter every time the login page is accessed, not necessarily when a login attempt is made.
We would like to track actual login attempts (i.e., when a user submits the login form with some credentials), may be we need to place the counter code in the form submission handling logic instead.

We are using stand forms:

```
@AnonymousAllowed
@PageTitle("Login")
@Route(value = "login")
@RouteAlias(value = "")
public class LoginView extends LoginOverlay implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    private final AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser;
    private String errorMessage;

    public LoginView(AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser) {
        this.authenticatedUser = authenticatedUser;
        setAction(RouteUtil.getRoutePath(VaadinService.getCurrent().getContext(), getClass()));

        LoginI18n i18n = LoginI18n.createDefault();
        i18n.setHeader(new LoginI18n.Header());
        i18n.getHeader().setTitle("Guard");
        i18n.getHeader().setDescription("Enter login and pass");
        i18n.setAdditionalInformation(null);
        i18n.getForm().setTitle("Authorisation");
        i18n.getForm().setUsername("Login");
        i18n.getForm().setPassword("Pass");
        i18n.getForm().setSubmit("Enter");
        setI18n(i18n);

        setForgotPasswordButtonVisible(false);
        setOpened(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        if (authenticatedUser.get().isPresent()) {
            setOpened(false);
            UserEntity user = authenticatedUser.get().get();
            System.out.println("------- "+user.toString());
            if (user.getRole().equals(Role.ADMIN)) {
                event.forwardTo("admin");
            } else {
                event.forwardTo("home");
            }
        }
        setError(event.getLocation().getQueryParameters().getParameters().containsKey("error"));
    }
}
```

We tried adding logic of counter of attempt into beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) method, but it works only before entering username and only on sessions.

Comment: Where is AuthenticatedUser from? Why not solve this in the security
layer, that has very likely a total view of the situation and most
likely already comes with tools to throttle brute force attempts.  Then
add the service to the login view and display an error, that the user is
blocked - let the UI do UI concerns and not security concerns.

Comment: Hello, that would be great to slove it inside the Vaadin Security layer. But cannot find where the counter should be put.
Some idea?))

Comment: Hello! Specifically, I want to implement a feature that locks out a user after a certain number of incorrect password attempts.

Here's what I have in mind: When a user tries to log in, we'll check if their password is correct. If it's incorrect, we'll increment a counter associated with their account. If the counter reaches a certain number (say, 3 incorrect attempts), we'll then block the user's account.

I understand that this feature should be implemented at the security layer of the application, but I'm not sure how to modify the Vaadin security configuration to do this.